# Launchd flow of spawning new processes

Tags: macos, launchd, xpc, mach

I'm doing some research about the way launchd load it's services from plist files under `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` or via the command `launchctl load`

So far I've managed to gather some various sources and compose the following vague picture as I understand it:

Upon Service loading (`launchctl load`) The process `launchctl` send the launchd an appropriate XPC message, and then the `launchd` is forked into new process with the context of `xpcproxy`. 
This generic process, is waiting for another XPC call from the `launchd` to run it's real process context according to the launchDaemon plst.

Is this explanation sounds right ? perhaps anybody can help me make it more accurate ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a bit more complicated. The kernel is composed of two parts, BSD and the mach kernel; the latter being responsible for management of memory and process scheduling.

Each mach process has one or more mach tasks (really task port rights!). When an application is first launched, it has just one right, the bootstrap port, allowing communication with launchd. Note that a task port right is uni-directional, so a launching process that has the right to communicate with launchd must give a right for launchd to communicate back to it.

When an XPC message is received by launchd, it depends upon the Launch Daemon as to what action it takes. It's possible that the message is for a service that runs with a network port that may or may not be running. If running, it forwards any arguments from the calling process to the running service. If not running, it can provide the service on demand by launching the process first.

More specifically you asked about `launchctl load`. Since the source code for launchd is no longer open source, the next best resource is the reverse engineering work by Jonathan Levin; Author of [Mac OS X and iOS Internals](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mac-OS-Internals-Approach-paperback/dp/0321278542) and more recently, his newer self-published books on [*OS Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/099105556X).

You'll find his slides about launchd [here](http://technologeeks.com/docs/launchd.pdf), but probably more useful to you is his version of launchctl, [jlaunchctl](http://newosxbook.com/articles/jlaunchctl.html) which is [open source](http://newosxbook.com/files/jlaunchctl.tgz).

Finally, if you want to view content of XPC messages between processes, disable SIP and use Jonathan's invaluable [XPoCe](http://newosxbook.com/tools/XPoCe2.html) tool.